# Здравствуйте у меня выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
> Введите значения m:3.13
> Введите значения v:-8.1 

Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "C:/Users/гоголя 8/Desktop/Итог 1/09.py", line 4,
> in <module>
>     z=((9*math.pi*v+10*math.cos(m))/(math.sqrt(v)-math.fabs(math.sin(v))))*math.pow(math.e,m)
> ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вообще такая ошибка бывает при недопустимых операциях - корень из отрицательного числа, например.

Answer (score 1):

```
9math.piv
```

забыли знак поставить

```
9*math.piv
```

Comment: Там есть знак на самом деле, просто автоформатер не так понимает

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь взять корень из отрицательного числа. Стандартная библиотека `math` такого не умеет.

```
math.sqrt(v) # v = -8.1
```

Текст ошибки скорее всего связан с этим.